# How to fix "IndexError: list index out of range" in Tensorflow

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm creating an Image Classifier using Tensorflow and Keras, but when I tried to train my model I got an error:

> IndexError: list index out of range.

I think the problem is with my model, because when I remove the conv2D layers, then the code throws no error.

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3),activation='relu',padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3),activation='relu',padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPool2D((2,2),strides=(2,2)))

model.add(Conv2D(128,(3,3),activation='relu',padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(128,(3,3),activation='relu',padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPool2D((2,2),strides=(2,2)))

model.add(Conv2D(256,(3,3),activation='relu',padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(256,(3,3),activation='relu',padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(256,(3,3),activation='relu',padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPool2D((2,2),strides=(2,2)))

model.add(Conv2D(512,(3,3),activation='relu',padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(512,(3,3),activation='relu',padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(512,(3,3),activation='relu',padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPool2D((2,2),strides=(2,2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(4096,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(4096,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(2,activation='softmax'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
metrices=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train,y_train,epochs=10)

#What is wrong in this model?
```

The error I got is:

```
    IndexError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-49-83b981a8bf39> in <module>()
----> 1 model.fit(x_train,y_train,10)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
   1534         steps_name='steps_per_epoch',
   1535         steps=steps_per_epoch,
-> 1536         validation_split=validation_split)
   1537 
   1538     # Prepare validation data.

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_shape.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    614         return TensorShape(self._dims[key])
    615       else:
--> 616         return self._dims[key]
    617     else:
    618       if isinstance(key, slice):

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Can you also print the shape of `x_train` and `y_train`?

Comment: It seems like you forgot to add the `input_shape` in the first layer. And there is a argument error within `model_compile`. The argument should be `metrics` instead of `metrices`.

Comment: Yeah, as @danyfang pointed out, you are missing "input_shape=" parameter from first Conv2D layer and also it is 'metrics' not metrices. You made a typo, I think.

Comment: @danyfang  Thanks, adding the input_shape worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elaborating the Comment of @Anubhav Singh in the Answer clearly for the benefit of Community.

After `model = Sequential()`, the first Convolution Layer should include the `input_shape` as one its arguments.

Example Code Snippet can be shown below:

```
model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3),activation='relu',input_shape=(28,28,1), adding='same'))
```

One more correction needed is in the line, `model.compile`. Name of the argument should be `metrics` instead of `metrices`.