# return self._dims[key].value IndexError: list index out of range Tensorflow indexError

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, tensorflow2.0

in tensor flow I made a regular network that takes hash as input. as an example I used the builtin python  `hash()` function (yes, it is changing the salt every session but this is an example)
the code is this:

```
from time import time
st = time()
import tensorflow as tf
print(time() - st)
import numpy as np
import chess
import atexit
from numpy import shape
data = open("data.data", "r").readlines()[:10000]
targets = open("targets.data", "r").readlines()[:10000]
boards_data = []
new_targets = []
for i in data:
    boards_data.append(hash(i))
for i in targets:
    new_targets.append(float(i))
print(len(new_targets))
print(len(boards_data))
print(np.array(new_targets))
print(np.array(boards_data))

def create_model():
   model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
   model.add(tf.keras.layers.Reshape((1,1,1)))
   model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1000, activation="tanh"))
   model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
   model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='tanh'))
   model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer="adam", metrics=['accuracy'])
   return model

model = create_model()
model.fit(np.array(boards_data), np.array(new_targets), epochs=10)
model.predict(np.array(hash("8/6P1/5k1K/6r1/8/8/8/8 b - - 0 83")))
```

the error is on the predict. I saw the conv2d example at [How to fix "IndexError: list index out of range" in Tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56155048/how-to-fix-indexerror-list-index-out-of-range-in-tensorflow)
but this isn't the case...

and the traceback:

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Volumes/POOPOO USB/lichess-bot/engines/engine2/nn_evaluation/nn_evaluation2.py", line 36, in <module>
    model.predict(np.array(hash("8/6P1/5k1K/6r1/8/8/8/8 b - - 0 83")))
  File "/Users/ofek/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 130, in _method_wrapper
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/ofek/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 1569, in predict
    data_handler = data_adapter.DataHandler(
  File "/Users/ofek/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py", line 1105, in __init__
    self._adapter = adapter_cls(
  File "/Users/ofek/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py", line 275, in __init__
    num_samples = set(int(i.shape[0]) for i in nest.flatten(inputs))
  File "/Users/ofek/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py", line 275, in <genexpr>
    num_samples = set(int(i.shape[0]) for i in nest.flatten(inputs))
  File "/Users/ofek/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py", line 887, in __getitem__
    return self._dims[key].value
IndexError: list index out of range```
````

Comment: Please update your post with the full error trace, as in the thread you link to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are creating a 0d numpy string from the hash value.. Prediction can only be run on an array with at least one dimension.
You can check that your hashed value is 0d:

```
print(np.array(hash("8/6P1/5k1K/6r1/8/8/8/8 b - - 0 83")).shape)
# outputs: ()
```

Versus if you put your hash value into a list:

```
print(np.array([hash("8/6P1/5k1K/6r1/8/8/8/8 b - - 0 83")]).shape)
# outputs: (1,)
```

With the second `np.array` the prediction runs without error.

Comment: Prediction should not interfere with your training, and I do not have you data or else to check what might be the error. I suggest opening a new question detailing the new problem you are facing.